# wp_redirect not working after concatenating

Tags: php, wordpress, string

I am trying to redirect frontend users after deleting their post from frontend. I am using the get_delete_post_link and then redirecting by using the following code:

```php
add_action( 'trashed_post', 'dex_redirect_after_trashing', 10 );

function dex_redirect_after_trashing() {
    $authorName = get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename' );
    $myWeb = home_url('/');
    $targetUrl = $myWeb . $authorName;
    wp_redirect( $targetUrl );
    exit;
}
```

I am trying to redirect to a url format like this "`www.mysite.com/$author`"
Currently its redirecting to the home url.
Desclaimer: I am a newbie.

Comment: `get_the_author_meta` tries to determine _which_ user you want meta data for automatically from the context - but that information is likely not available in the context of this hook. The `trashed_post` hook callback gets the post id passed as parameter though - so you will need to use that to get the author ID from the post first, which you can then pass to `get_the_author_meta` as the second parameter.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe for the clarification. I implemented what you suggested and it seems to be working fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) above in the comments, the `get_the_author_meta` needed author ID as a second parameter.
Here is the revised code:

```
add_action( 'trashed_post', 'dex_redirect_after_trashing', 10 );
function dex_redirect_after_trashing() {
$authorID = get_post_field( 'post_author', get_the_ID() );
$authorName = get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename', $authorID );
$myWeb = home_url('/');
$targetUrl = $myWeb . $authorName;
wp_redirect( $targetUrl );
exit;
}
```

The code is working as it supposed to be. Any further improvement or critic is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `/author/` part in the Link.

```
add_action( 'trashed_post', 'dex_redirect_after_trashing', 10 );
function dex_redirect_after_trashing() {
$authorName = get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename' );
$myWeb = home_url('/');
$targetUrl = $myWeb . 'author/' . $authorName;
wp_redirect( $targetUrl );
exit;
```

Comment: Actually I omitted the "/author/"  base intentionally as I have custom pages for the authors. I found the answer by implementing CBroe suggestion in the comments above. Thanks anyway.